# Getting error when running update-database for MySql database: Table 'xxx' doesn't exist

Tags: c#, mysql, ef-code-first

I have recently changed some properties in my class (Notification) and as usual I added a migration for the changes. 
I ran the update-database command and got an error saying the table 'xxx.dbo.notifications' doesn't exist.

The table is still there so why am I getting this error?

Edit: the migration code

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Notifications", "PaymentId", "dbo.Payments");
        DropIndex("dbo.Notifications", new[] { "PaymentId" });
        AddColumn("dbo.Notifications", "ProductOptionId", c => c.Int());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Notifications", "PaymentId", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Notifications", "PaymentId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Notifications", "ProductOptionId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Notifications", "ProductOptionId", "dbo.ProductOptions", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Notifications", "PaymentId", "dbo.Payments", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Notifications", "PaymentId", "dbo.Payments");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Notifications", "ProductOptionId", "dbo.ProductOptions");
        DropIndex("dbo.Notifications", new[] { "ProductOptionId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Notifications", new[] { "PaymentId" });
        AlterColumn("dbo.Notifications", "PaymentId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        DropColumn("dbo.Notifications", "ProductOptionId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Notifications", "PaymentId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Notifications", "PaymentId", "dbo.Payments", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
```

Edit: I reverted the changes to before the error occurred. I added the ProductOptionId property to the model, added the migration, and updated the database successfully.

The problem seems to be happening when I'm changing the PaymentId property to null-able.

Does that make sense?

Comment: This does not look like MySQL, this seems to be ms sql server.

Comment: @Shadow What makes you think that?

Comment: `xxx.dbo.notifications` - in MySQL you can have `xxx.notifications` table, or `xxx.dbo` table, but cannot have 3 elements in the path. Table is only associated with the database (schema).

Comment: I can assure you it's MySQL. I have the following line in the migrations configuration cos of it: SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());  This is the first time I'm having this issue

Comment: Your database may be MySQL, but the table name in the error message cannot exist in MySQL. Period.

Comment: Do you have a schema called `dbo` in MySQL? If not, why do you use `dbo` as a prefix in the script?

Comment: I don't have a schema called dbo. That is auto-generated when adding the migrations.

Comment: Then you probably use an incorrect generator. No MySQL generator would add dbo to the table names.

Answer (score 0):

1- Make Sure That Table Is Created Into database after Your Migration 
2- Make Sure That The Context Is Refereeing to The Same Database That You Have Migrated to

Comment: The table existed before already. I just changed some properties and added new ones. I'm also working with just one context.

Comment: how did you add properties?
from Your Model Class And After That You Made Migration Or Directly from Your Database management 
and i mean that to make sure the context connection string is not changed dynamically before you run the application

Comment: I added properties from my model class and after I made a migration. I never touch it from my database management so I don't cause any problems.

Comment: so can you check your migration script file and let me see it ,it may deleted table by mistake